# How to integrate finger print attendance into ASP.NET Core MVC app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, fingerprint

I want to add fingerprint feature to my ASP.NET Core MVC application. I want staff to register their attendance by their thumb on a fingerprint scanner. Any ideas to how to go about the project?

Comment: When you will buy the `finger print` device they will provide you software along with some guideline. That device will produce a excel files containing the `in-out` of each entry. From your application all you need to read that file path and upload into your database from that excel. Then you can do anything you want. So firsly make sure what kind of your `findger print device` is? how it would export the information based on that you have to move next steps.

Comment: Thank you so much.  can you suggest any good device?

Comment: There are lot of actually, you can discuss with the supplier regarding your requuirement and what feature they are providing so that you can get more idea.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.